# Get the childs array of the passed in category Php Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Here is my problem, im failing to dynamically loop through a nested array and get the childs of the passed in category name. In my data its represented as slug. For example if i pass in a category called hygiene i want to get all the childs, and the same should happen if i pass in category called dishwasher all the childs should come.

```
[
  {
    "categories_id": 1,
    "image_path": "images/media/2020/11/qujIz11610.jpg",
    "slug": "hygiene",
    "categories_name": "Hygiene",
    "parent_id": 0,
    "childs": [
      {
        "categories_id": 2,
        "image_path": "images/media/2020/11/qujIz11610.jpg",
        "slug": "dishwasher",
        "categories_name": "Dishwasher",
        "parent_id": 1,
        "childs": [
          {
            "categories_id": 3,
            "image_path": "images/media/2020/11/qujIz11610.jpg",
            "slug": "sunlight",
            "categories_name": "Sunlight",
            "parent_id": 2
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "categories_id": 4,
        "image_path": "images/media/2020/11/qujIz11610.jpg",
        "slug": "toilet-clear",
        "categories_name": "Toilet Clear",
        "parent_id": 1,
        "childs": [
          {
            "categories_id": 5,
            "image_path": "images/media/2020/11/qujIz11610.jpg",
            "slug": "boom-toilet-cleaner",
            "categories_name": "Boom Toilet Cleaner",
            "parent_id": 4
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "categories_id": 6,
    "image_path": "images/media/2020/11/qujIz11610.jpg",
    "slug": "breakfast",
    "categories_name": "Breakfast",
    "parent_id": 0,
    "childs": [
      {
        "categories_id": 7,
        "image_path": "images/media/2020/11/qujIz11610.jpg",
        "slug": "cereals",
        "categories_name": "Cereals",
        "parent_id": 6,
        "childs": [
          {
            "categories_id": 8,
            "image_path": "images/media/2020/11/qujIz11610.jpg",
            "slug": "corn-flakes",
            "categories_name": "Corn Flakes",
            "parent_id": 7,
            "childs": [
              {
                "categories_id": 9,
                "image_path": "images/media/2020/11/qujIz11610.jpg",
                "slug": "willards",
                "categories_name": "Willards",
                "parent_id": 8
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here is what i have tried

```
foreach($result['categories'] as $category)
          {
             if($category->slug === $request->category and isset($category->childs)){
                    $parameter['children_size'] = sizeOf($category->childs);
          
                    break;
             }else{
                $parameter['children_size'] = 0;
    
             }
          }
```

So my iteration function is rigid to only getting the childs of the first categories.Can someone help me here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, what output are you expecting from your example ?
Have you heard of laravel collections ? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections
I think you should try and get a grip on this documentation, I believe there are some useful methods that can help you. Regards

Comment: okay, let me take a look at it,